# Pull HTML Value into Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-spinner

I have a table with multiple columns with one column being a checkbox. Whenever that is checked, it displays another column cell to the right of the table with an up/down spinner to set a value.

The problem I am having is that I cannot have the spinner go past the number that is in the Quantity column that I have. So I need to pull the current value of the Quantity column in the corresponding row into a javascript variable and use that with my spinner function. I have been able to get the value using `getElementById` but that only gets the first value in the table and does not work for any further values down in the table. I keep trying `getElementsByClassName` but am having no luck.

How could I do this successfully?

PHP/HTML:

```
<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" id="loc-<?php echo intval ($row['Loc'])?>"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku ui-widget-content" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description ui-widget-content" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit ui-widget-content" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" name="value" id="test"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript...I am trying to pull in the value using the `quantity` variable. Every time I select a checkbox, the `console.log(quantity)` comes back with `undefined`:

```
$(function () {
    $(".check").change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
    console.log($('input.check').is(':checked'));
    var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity').innerHTML;
        console.log(quantity);

  if($('input.check').is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(true);
    else
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(false);



    $( ".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 0 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 0 );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements, not just one. That's why it's "Elements" plural.

Comment: Why mix jquery and javascript? use $(".quantity').val()

Comment: you need to get current value like this 
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').text();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').html();
```

It's recommended putting that value in a data property:

```
<td class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
```

And then you can access that value from jQuery:

```
var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
```

This way you don't depend on HTML. Imagine that tomorrow, in that cell, you want to use a `<span>` or add units to quantity. If your data is in a property, you don't depend on what is actually inside the cell.

Comment: `<td>` elements don't have a `value` property.

Comment: I never thought of doing it that way. Good solution.

Comment: This works, however, if I have two checkboxes checked, then it will only let me set the spinner equal to a max of the quantity column in the most recent checkbox that was checked. So one column could have 60 quantity and one have 5 quantity, but if the quantity 5 column was checked most recently, then the quantity 60 column will only be able to go to 5 in the spinner instead of 60....how could i fix that?

Comment: It happens because in each checkbox you're attaching the spinner plugin to *all* elements with class `spinner`. Change it to `$( $(this).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({ ...`

Comment: Also, as you're calling many times to `$(this).closest("tr")`, it's better caching the element in a variable: `$tr = $(this).closest("tr");` .

Answer (score 2):

You can't grab the `innerHTML` property for an entire class (list of nodes).

You have:

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity').innerHTML;
```

If you change it to the line below, where, it should work:

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to get current row value like this

```
var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').text();
```